# Angular Material Radio Button Checked

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've this component code (I just keep the code needed to throw this error):

```
    import {
      Component,
      OnInit,
      ChangeDetectorRef
    } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  /**/
})
export class ManageUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  public dataSource: UserDataSource | null;
  public users: IUser[] = [];
  public metadata: Metadata[] = [];
  public displayedColumns = [
    'lastname',
    'firstname',
    'email',
    'administrator',
    'advancedUser',
    'collaborator',
    'actions'
  ];

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    onChange(): void {
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataSource = null;

    // Get users from server
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(response => {

        let _users = response.users;
        this.metadata = response.metadata;

        for (let i = 0; i < _users.length; i++) {
            this.users.push(_users[i]);
        }

        // Set data table source
        this.dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.users);

    }, errorResponse => {
        console.log(errorResponse);
    });
    }
}
```

I've this template code:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="administrator">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Administrateur </mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
             <mat-radio-button color="primary" 
                           name="radio_{{user.id}}"
                           checked="true"
                           value="ROLE_ADMIN"
                           (change)="setRoles($event, user)">
         </mat-radio-button>
         {{user.authorities[0]?.name == 'ROLE_ADMIN'}} <!-- This is true -->
     </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'false'
```

I've read about this error, but can't understand it how can I fix it on this context. This is a view, I'm just changing the checked attribute from material design.

The problem is with the checked attribute.

Can anyone help me?

Than you in advance.

Best regards,
Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject `ChangeDetectionRef` into your component

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef) {
}

onChange(): void {
  this.val += 1; // <- get error after
  this.cdr.detectionChanges();
}
```

Or call the `enableProdMode()` from your `main.ts` file

Comment: Hi. I've updated my initial question. I've tried that before but still with errors. And this `ChangeDetectionRef` should be `ChangeDetectorRef`, at least in the version 4.3.1. Thanks.